# Duplicate values in combobox in QT Designer form

Tags: qgis, qt, combo-box, qt-designer

I have a custom form created with QT Designer on which I have several comboboxes among other stuff. All the fields have the correct names corresponding to the database.

But something weird and frustrating happens when I'm trying to use the form in QGIS. All the comboboxes except one, when I click on them, they display duplicate values of the original values I have designed them with. E.g if the combobox originally has the values 1,2 and 3, when I click on it, it displays 1,2,3,1,2,3 or 1,2,3,2,3 or 1,2,3,3,1 or some other combination of the existing values.

If I choose from the first tuple of the values (the original ones), nothing is stored in the database. If I choose a value from the duplicates it is correctly stored. The one combobox that displays only the correct values (no duplicates) doesn't store anything in the database. What's up with that?

Comment: The same answer as to my other question applies http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/89567/qt-designer-form-combobox-stores-value-but-doesnt-display-it/89574#89574

Answer (score 1):

First, create your combobox in Qt Designer without any values. Then save your form and join it to your layer in QGIS.

Now, in the properties of your layer, go to the Field tab. Here you can add values to your empty combobox: click on Text edit and change it to Value map. Add your values in the table displayed and click OK.